# SOAP header Security was not understood

Tags: soapheader

I'm using a asp.net 3.5 C# as a webservice consumer and I'm trying to consume a third party java webservice and I have already attached the soap header security on my request. There is no problem on my request but the response part I'm getting "SOAP header Security was not understood." maybe I missed some configuration on my end or something on the java side?

Here's the response envelope:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header>
      <wsse:Security env:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsu:Created>2011-10-12T01:15:43.484Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2011-10-12T01:20:43.484Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
      </wsse:Security>
   </env:Header>
   <env:Body>
      <pv:StatusResponse xmlns:pv="http://tempuri.org/lps" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <pv:status>0</pv:status>
      </pv:StatusResponse>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that's the response envelope, not the request?  You could try removing the `mustUnderstand="1"` attribute, and see if the security works from there...

Comment: Yes. Im using Fiddler to get the response. How to remove the mustUnderstand="1"? because the response is from the 3rd party java webservice and i dont have the control. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I end up downgrading the entire project from VS2008 down to VS2005 in order to maximize the WSE3.0 features and functionality. XD